# Why not used the index in left join of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using two tables as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_purchase_event_join` (
   `ind` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `wtime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `event_ind` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `id` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `point` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `cnt` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `memo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `purchase_ind` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`ind`),   KEY `id` (`id`),
   KEY `event_ind` (`event_ind`)
 );
```

And,

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_user` (
  `ind` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,

  ....
   KEY `id` (`id`),
);
```

I tested two sqls and showed the results of 'explain'.

```
select tpej.*, tu.nickname, tu.level from tb_purchase_event_join tpej left join tb_user tu on tu.id = tpej.id
```

Explain Results:

```
1   SIMPLE  tpej        ALL                 37  100.00  
1   SIMPLE  tu      ALL                 137876  100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

And this,

```
select tpej.*, tu.nickname, tu.level from tb_purchase_event_join tpej join tb_user tu on tu.id = tpej.id
```

Explain Results:

```
1   SIMPLE  tu      ALL                 137877  100.00  
1   SIMPLE  tpej        ref id  id  482 func    1   100.00  Using index condition
```

Why does not left join use the index?

What's the matter?

Comment: First problem that jumps to me is that fact that `tu.id (varchar(120) collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)` is different from `tpej.id (varchar(128) ... no specified collation)`  so when joining the indexes will probably not match.

Can you fix that and try again?

Comment: LEFT JOIN would be used if u not expect an result, so the query fills, therefore empty joins with NULL

Comment: @AlexandreVoyer, Results are the same.

Comment: Did you actually fix the collation? Alex is right, MySQL cannot properly use the index with mismatched collations. See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0977eb67c4ba11e06c5414f66cb69900) - with matching collation, you get the expected query plan.

Comment: @Solarflare, but yet, the second sql didn't used index field.